# I'd like to put multiples repetition of a list in data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table, rep

I'm trying to create this table:

```
library(data.table)
table <-  data.table(
    x = "D"  ,
    y = list(c("a", "b"), c("a", "b"),c("a", "b"),c("a", "b"), "test"))
table
```

I'd like to use rep() with maybe list():

```
table <- data.table(
    x = "D"  ,
    y = list(rep(c("a", "b"), 4), "test")
  )
```

But that's not the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replicate a list and use `c(...)` to make a new list out of the previous list and `"test"`:

```
library(data.table)
table1 <-  data.table(
  x = "D"  ,
  y = list(c("a", "b"), c("a", "b"),c("a", "b"),c("a", "b"), "test"))
table1


table2 <- data.table(
  x = "D"  ,
  y = c(rep(list(c("a", "b")), 4), "test")
)

identical(table1,table2) 
[1] TRUE
```